# Data in table is not resolved correctly after Oracle 11g to MSSQL2012 migration

Tags: sql-server-2008, oracle11g, sql-server-2012, database-migration

We have recently migrated a database from Oracle 11g to SQL Server 2012 SP1. We also performed migrated that same database from Oracle 11g to SQL Server 2008 R2.

The database migration from Oracle to SQL Server 2008 has been performed successfully; our application can exploit that database without any issues. We have however encountered a problem with the migration from Oracle to SQL Server 2012 SP1.

When retrieving data from a specific column (type: VARCHAR(MAX)), in some cases, instead of having the content of the stored string displayed, we only have a "/" displayed. When we look at the data stored in the column, everything is there. Our application uses and OBDC configured with the MSSQL11 driver.

What we also observed:

- The varchar(max) column is retrieved successfully when using the MSSQL10 driver;

Is there anything that we might have to change to make this work? Don't hesitate to ask for more information.

Thank you!

Comment: Do you mean the varchar(max) column is retrieved successfully when using the MSSQL10 driver? What is the DATALENGTH() for the varchar max column on rows that are being returned as "/"?

Comment: @supergrady Yes, the varchar(max) column is retrieved succesfully when using the MSSQL10 driver, I will specify this point. As for the DATALENGTH() for that column, it is 4650.

Comment: Hmm. What is the compatibility level of the database?

Comment: @supergrady The compatibility level of the database is SQL Server 2012 (110)